# config.json missing

Tags: node

Was working on saving my identity, peers and config jsons for the switch to full when I noticed the /.tezos.node folder is missing a config.json file. There are the following jsons in that folder. identity, peers, version but no config. Node and baker etc worked flawlessly until now. What gives?

Answer (score 4):

You can make a new config file with the below command.

```
./tezos-node config init
```

Answer (score 2):

The config.json file is optional, if it is not present the the node uses sensible defaults